# Java -Multiplicar os objetos quando uma das chaves principais é um array

Tags: java, array, objetos, json

Esse método precisa ser em Java.

No momento utilizo um método de flatten, mas ele não atende.

Recebo um array de objetos e preciso multiplicar os objetos quando uma das chaves principais é um array. Segue um exemplo de como recebo o array e de como quero devolvê-lo.

Array recebido:

```java
[{
    "Pipeline": {
        "Name": "Geral Domovel",
        "Id": "79",
        "Sort": "200",
        "Created_Date": "2022-01-10T01:00:0000",
        "Is_Locked": "N",
    },
    "Stages": [
        {
            "Name": "Criação",
            "Status_Id": "C79:7",
            "Sort": "80",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Aguardar",
            "Status_Id": "C79:2",
            "Sort": "30",
        },
    ]
},
{
    "Pipeline": {
        "Name": "Geral Domovel",
        "Id": "79",
        "Sort": "200",
        "Created_Date": "2022-01-10T01:00:0000",
        "Is_Locked": "N",
    },
    "Stages": [
        {
            "Name": "Criação",
            "Status_Id": "C79:7",
            "Sort": "80",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Aguardar",
            "Status_Id": "C79:2",
            "Sort": "30",
        },
    ]
}]
```

Resposta pretendida:

```java
[{
    "Pipeline": {
        "Name": "Geral Domovel",
        "Id": "79",
        "Sort": "200",
        "Created_Date": "2022-01-10T01:00:0000",
        "Is_Locked": "N",
    },
    "Stages": {
        "Name": "Criação",
        "Status_Id": "C79:7",
        "Sort": "80",
    }

},
{
    "Pipeline": {
        "Name": "Geral Domovel",
        "Id": "79",
        "Sort": "200",
        "Created_Date": "2022-01-10T01:00:0000",
        "Is_Locked": "N",
    },
    "Stages": {
        "Name": "Aguardar",
        "Status_Id": "C79:2",
        "Sort": "30",
    }

},
{
    "Pipeline": {
        "Name": "Geral Domovel",
        "Id": "79",
        "Sort": "200",
        "Created_Date": "2022-01-10T01:00:0000",
        "Is_Locked": "N",
    },
    "Stages": {
        "Name": "Criação",
        "Status_Id": "C79:7",
        "Sort": "80",
    }

},
{
    "Pipeline": {
        "Name": "Geral Domovel",
        "Id": "79",
        "Sort": "200",
        "Created_Date": "2022-01-10T01:00:0000",
        "Is_Locked": "N",
    },
    "Stages": {
        "Name": "Aguardar",
        "Status_Id": "C79:2",
        "Sort": "30",
    }
}]
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo, pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar.

Answer (score 0):

O trabalho pode ser feito usando streams (ver https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Esquematicamente você pode seguir o exemplo abaixo em JavaScript, para entender o mecanismo....

```
var arr = [{
    "Pipeline": {
        "Name": "Geral Domovel",
        "Id": "79",
        "Sort": "200",
        "Created_Date": "2022-01-10T01:00:0000",
        "Is_Locked": "N",
    },
    "Stages": [
        {
            "Name": "Criação",
            "Status_Id": "C79:7",
            "Sort": "80",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Aguardar",
            "Status_Id": "C79:2",
            "Sort": "30",
        },
    ]
}...

var result = arr.flatMap(item=>{
   var pipeline = item.Pipeline; // Pipeline
   var stages = item.Stages;     // Array de Stages
   return stages.map(stage=> {
     return {
         Pipeline: pipeline,
         Stages: stage
        }
   });
});
```

Exemplo: https://playcode.io/1005264

Ou em Java, preenchendo as classes com os métodos corretamente e fazendo o parse do JSON para algo parecido, segue o mesmo conceito...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass {
    
    public static class Pipeline {
        String Name;
        String Id;
        String Sort;
        String Created_Date;
        String Is_Locked;
        public Pipeline() {} public Pipeline(String name, String id, String sort, String date, String isLocked) {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Id = id;
            this.Sort = sort;
            this.Created_Date = date;
            this.Is_Locked = isLocked;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{ Name: \"%s\", Id: %s, Sort: %s, Created_Date: %s, Is_Locked: %s}" , Name, Id, Sort, Created_Date, Is_Locked);
        }
    }
    
    public static class Stages {
        String Name;
        String Status_Id;
        String Sort;
        public Stages() {} public Stages(String name, String status, String sort) {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Status_Id = status;
            this.Sort = sort;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{ Name: \"%s\", Status_Id: %s, Sort: %s}" , Name, Status_Id, Sort);
        }
    }
    
    public static class ArrayItem {
        Pipeline Pipeline;
        List<Stages> Stages;
        ArrayItem() {} ArrayItem(Pipeline pipe, Stages... stages) { this.Pipeline = pipe; this.Stages = Arrays.asList(stages); }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{Pipeline: " + Pipeline + ", Stages: [" + 
                this.Stages.stream().map(item->item.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
                + "]}";
        }
    }
    
    public static class ResultItem {
        Pipeline Pipeline;
        Stages Stages;
        ResultItem() {} ResultItem(Pipeline pipe, Stages stages) { this.Pipeline = pipe; this.Stages = stages; }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{Pipeline: " + Pipeline + ", Stages: " + Stages + "}";
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        List<ArrayItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ArrayItem(
                new Pipeline(),
                new Stages(),
                new Stages()
            ));
        System.out.println(list);
            
        List<ResultItem> result = list.stream().flatMap(item->{
            return item.Stages.stream().map(s->{
                return new ResultItem(item.Pipeline, s);
            });
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).